# pass parameter cron job file execute command in phpvibe with PHP

Tags: php, cron, jobs, phpvibe

we have source file like this:

```
$binpath = get_option('binpath', '/usr/bin/php');
$command = $binpath . ABSPATH . "/videocron-premium.php plan_id='$plan_id'";
exec("$command > /dev/null &", $arrOutput);
```

that want to send parameter to this file

this is part of my file:

```
parse_str($argv[1], $params);
$plan_id = $params['plan_id'];
```

i want to get parameter in this php cron file.

This parse_str didnt work for me!

how can i parse $argv and continue my algorithm

Comment: So, `parse_str($argv[1], $params);` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to get plan_id

```
foreach ($argv as $arg) {
if (stripos($arg, "plan_id") !== false) {
    $plan_id = substr($arg, 8);
}
}
```

Comment: yes its worked for me on linux cron job thank you. how can we trace a code in cron job?